# Mercurial feature work - keeping bespoke work clean best practise?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, workflow, branch, rebase

I've been using source control systems for about 10 years, each obviously with their own idioms and practises.

I am currently using Mercurial for .NET development and have a particular requirement that I wonder what your opinions would be to best achieve my goal.

We develop a baseline product that is a kind of rolling release. Some customers need the product slimmed down (due to getting cheaper licenses) or bespoke work done. I tend to branch the "trunk" (default branch in Mercurial), do the bespoke work and create a build.

When new work is done in "trunk" and I need a new build from the bespoke branch, I will merge the changes using `hg merge -r CHANGESET_NUM_FROM_DEFAULT_HERE` and then do a build.

This works fine, but the bespoke branch quickly gets filled with commits that are related to "trunk" and not really bespoking features. This means when I need to look through the changesets for this branch they are cluttered.

What I really want it to shift where the branch "junction point"  begins, so the bespoke changelist only contains bespoke check-ins, but the parent of the bespoke branch changes.

I tried to use the rebase extension as this looks like it should do this, but it instead does many merges and still clutters up my bespoke branch.

Is there a way of keeping my bespoke branch clean? Or am I going about things the wrong way?

Comment: For the non-British, "bespoke" means "custom".  I had to look it up :)

Comment: Thanks Mark, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bespoke branch **is** clean now. But - if you want don't see mergesets in branch log, just skip in log

`hg help log`

> options:
>
> ...
>
> -M --no-merges           do not show merges

`hg log -r 55:tip --template "{branch}:{rev}\n" -b default`

> default:55
>
> default:56
>
> default:57
>
> **default:60**
>
> default:61
>
> **default:63**
>
> default:65
>
> default:66

`hg log -r 55:tip --template "{branch}:{rev}\n" -b default -M`

> default:55
>
> default:56
>
> default:57
>
> default:61
>
> default:65
>
> default:66

and screenshot of graph from THG

[image: Merges]

Comment: Thanks, your answer does allow me to easily look through the clean change sets so does indeed answer my question - but do you think my approach to branching small bespoke changes like this is a good practise or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: @tommed - can't see anything bad in your workflow. "Better way" is subjective and developer-dependend. "Don't break unbroken" is ol'good rule

Comment: Thanks! I would have been better to define "better" as the communal opinion from an aggregation of people with good experience because they've done it one way and later wished they really hadn't!! :)

Comment: @tommed - from this POV I can note 1. "branch-per-task" workflow: each atomic task developed in short-live branch, evey development-aggregation branch contain **only** mergesets (for the cost of "clean" log with revsets become more complex) 2. For upstream-fork sometimes MQ-patches may be usable: repo is clean, customer-related changes are named sets of MQ-pathes, some subsets of which are (qpop/qpush/qgoto) applied to vanilla code